# Isotope image grid - run function on init and after images are resized

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-isotope

I have this function I need to run on isotope init and every time items are resized. So I try to apply it like this:

```
$('.isotope-grid').each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('blue')) var blue = true;
    updateColor(blue, index);
    $(this).isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        layoutMode: 'masonry'
    });
    $(this).isotope( 'on', 'layoutComplete', updateColor(blue, index));
});
```

On init everything works fine, but on resize it seems function is not triggered. Aditionally I get following error:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined*

Here you have a fiddle for your convinience http://jsfiddle.net/9kaoqjfm/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it looks like the variable blue is only defined if the grid has the class "blue". Otherwise it is not even defined.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David DeSandro I have learned the solution. It appears that the listener should be wrapped in a function, like this

```
$(this).isotope('on', 'layoutComplete', function () {
      updateColor(blue, index);
    });
```

And a working fiddle is here -> http://jsfiddle.net/9kaoqjfm/1/

I hope it will become useful for someone :)